# Connect vpn on pc without vpn feature on router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

I am planning to buy a new router which have no VPN featue: https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c80/

My old router have VPN feature and it is enabled on the router, but I only use VPN on one PC and the VPN is configured locally on the PC.

My question is, could I connect to VPN on my PC with the archer-c80 router which have no VPN feature?

Note: other tp link routers have vpn feature like: https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-a7/, but I would like to go with the archer-c80

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a PC software based VPN. There are lots of options, for example PureVPN, ExpressVPN, custom VPNs, socks-based VPNs (proxies), etc.